# Create SAML Assertion for 3rd Party Application with custom data in Assertion Payload in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, saml

I am creating an application that needs to authenticate a User for a 3rd Party Application. The requirement is that I need to provide the 3rd Party a SAML Assertion Token which they verify.

So my application is acting as the Identity Provider, and the 3rd Party Application is the Service Provider.

I also need to include a load of user data within the payload of the SAML Assertion Token. The 3rd party once they receive the SAML token should then be able to extract this data.

My application will be a .NET Core application and once the user is authenticated I will redirect the user to a URL for the 3rd party application with the SAML Token in the Request Header.

Any ideas as to best achieve this. Ideally I'd want to use some standard library to construct the SAML Assertion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your IdP-implementation should use SAML protocol? I'm asking because your question isn't completely clear in this regard, because WS-Federation (in conjunction with SAML1.1 tokens) could be possible, too.

First of all, it'd be probably a good idea to not write your own IdP but use an existing product.

- If you want/have to stick with Microsoft technologies, then [AD FS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services) would be a good candidate for you. It's a Windows Server feature used on premise.
- Furthermore there are several commercial products (e.g. [Auth0](https://auth0.com/learn/saml-identity-provider/) or [Onelogin](https://www.onelogin.com/pages/saml)).
- Another existing product to be used on premise which is written in C# and is heavily customizable is [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/). Have a look at it. I'm not very familiar with it, but it seems to me that the support for SAML2 protocol isn't part of the free package and has to be paid.
- An alternative (just one, there are plenty) could be [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) if you're not bound to Microsoft.
- If you're about to write your IdP completly from scratch, then have a look at [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) which is a library that primarily focusses on implementing Service Providers but can be used for IdPs, too.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes it should use SAML protocol. I took a look at OneLogin but I couldn't see how you could add your own custom data into the SAML Payload. The Sustainsys seems to be ServiceProvider only

Comment: Yep, you'll probably have a quite hard time in customizing the non-onprem solutions :-/ Regarding Sustainsys: Please take a look [at the very bottom of this page](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/getting-started.html): _The protocol handling classes are available as a public API as well, making it possible to reuse some of the internals for writing your own service provider or identity provider._

Answer (score 0):

In the end , this seemed to be the best way of doing it. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/%2FArticles%2F56640%2FPerforming-a-SAML-Post-with-C